# Gaps between numbers of the form $pq$, part 2

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I asked this question: [Gaps between numbers of the form $pq$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280770/gaps-between-numbers-of-the-form-pq) , and received a very satisfactory answer. Now I'm curious about a related one. We know that we have have arbitrarily long stretches of numbers with no primes, so there is no upper bound on the gap between $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$, where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime.

For numbers of the form $pq$, i.e., products of two distinct primes, are there also arbitrarily long gaps between them? Or, is there a number $K$, such that for any natural number $n$, at least one of $n, n+1, \ldots, n+K-1$ is a product of two primes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, consider $K+1$ distinct primes $p_i$.  By the Chinese Remainder Theorem there is $N$ such that $N \equiv i \mod p_i^3$ for all $i$ from  $1$ to $K+1$.  Thus $N - i$ is divisible by $p_i^3$, and in particular is not a product of two primes, for all of these $i$.

Comment: Ooh, that's good. CRT to the rescue, once again. Thank you!